# Dump all databases with SSH access

Tags: ssh, mysql

I would like to know how to dump all databases into a folder.
I'm using a Linux/Debian
Afer connecting on the server with root access I make

```
$ mysql -u admin -p
```

To connect on mysql.

Then which commands are to extract all databases created in my Plesk Panel?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [**mysqldump**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html) command

```
mysqldump -u user -p --all-databases >file.sql
```

and a quick hack at a script which does much the same but puts the databases in individual files

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "show databases;" | mysql -u root --password='Password' | while read databa
sename
do
    echo dumping $databasename
    mysqldump -u root --password='Password' "$databasename" >"$databasename.sql"

done
```

Comment: This is the best. You realy help to me.

Comment: Worked like a champ solve all my problems. Now one more question is there any way to drop all the databases as well

Comment: thanks so much , you save me day

Answer (score 3):

If you have SSH access, you can the command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /path/to/outfile
```

Then, you can download the generated file.

Answer (score 2):

While connected with SSH, you can issue the following commands.

To dump all your MySQL databases:

```
mysqldump --user=<user> --password=<pwd> -A > /PATH/TO/DUMPFILE.SQL
```

If you want to dump specific databases:

```
mysqldump --user=<user> --password=<pwd> --databases DB_NAME1 DB_NAME2 DB_NAME3 > /PATH/TO/DUMPFILE.SQL
```

It's really that simple :)

Answer (score 1):

> Then which commands are to extract all databases created in my Plesk Panel?

What's plesk got to do with it?

Just ssh on and run [mysqldump](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysqldump/), writing the output to a directory you can read via ssh/ftp/http and download the files.