# Dropping all mysql databases using ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql5.6

I am totally new to the ssh so pardon if I commit any mistake.
Well, I have had 457 databases which i wanted to take backup and put databases in individual files. Which i got a working solution from this [Answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/338200/dump-all-databases-with-ssh-access). Now I have dumped all the databases now i want to **delete/drop all the databases** from MySQL. I have googled alot but didn't find a useful resource to my question or maybe i am not aware of terms so truly seeking for help.

Comment: What does SSH have to do with this?

Comment: Actually, i have shared web hosting from Bluehost and they blocked my access to PhpMyAdmin now the only way i have to use ssh to backup all of my databases and then delete it. The dumping part is done but deletion part is remaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the command `DROP DATABASE database_name` and need to do this for all databases. I do not think there is one command that will delete all databases at once.

You may try this while loop:

```
echo "show databases;" | mysql -u <username> -p <password>|while read databasename 
     do echo deleting $databasename
     drop database $databasename 
done
```